# MySQL regexp within subquery

Tags: mysql, regex, subquery

I have a very particular problem and after looking at many ressources, i'm unable to find a solution to my problem.

The MySQL version i'm running is MySQL 5.0.91

Given the following tables definition :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `item`;
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `code` varchar(4096) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records 
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('1', 'pizza|large|pepp');
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('3', 'pizza|medium|pepp');
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('2', 'pizza|small|pepp');
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('4', 'appetizer|fries|large');
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('5', 'beverage|2_liter|pepsi');
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('6', 'pizza|small|cheese');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `item_regexp`;
CREATE TABLE `item_regexp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `regexp` varchar(4096) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records 
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('1', '((pizza)\\\\|)((large|medium)\\\\|)');
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('2', '((pizza)\\\\|)((.*)\\\\|)((alldressed))');
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('3', '((beverage)\\\\|)((2_liter)\\\\|)');
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('4', '((pizza)\\\\|)((.*)\\\\|)((pepp))');
```

In summary, table item represents items on an invoice. In my example, I have 5 items. The code is an internal representation of that specific Item.

Then, the `item_regexp` table are used to specify possible product. This can be used for example to capture all possible product that satisfy a given code pattern to apply a discount, etc.

I would like to load all the `item_regexp` entries with the number of item each can capture from the list of items on an invoice.

Doing subquery to count the number of entries in table `item` that are captured by my regexp, gives me a proper result :

```
################
# QUERY #1     #
################
SELECT 
(SELECT
count(*)
FROM
item
where 
`item`.`code` REGEXP '((pizza)\\|)((large|medium)\\|)') as "regexp1 count"
,
(SELECT
count(*)
FROM
item
where 
`item`.`code` REGEXP '((pizza)\\|)((.*)\\|)((alldressed))') as "regexp2 count"
,
(SELECT
count(*)
FROM
item
where 
`item`.`code` REGEXP '((beverage)\\|)((2_liter)\\|)') as "regexp3 count" 
,
(SELECT
count(*)
FROM
item
where 
`item`.`code` REGEXP '((pizza)\\|)((.*)\\|)((pepp))') as "regexp4 count" ;
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| regexp1 count | regexp2 count | regexp3 count | regexp4 count |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|             2 |             0 |             1 |             3 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
1 row in set
```

However, running this as a subquery within a more general query seemed to always give 0 as a count. This is as if the regexp was not working or not taken into account.

```
################
# QUERY #2     #
################
SELECT 
`item_regexp`.`regexp`
, 
(
SELECT
count(*)
FROM
item
where 
`item`.`code` REGEXP `item_regexp`.`regexp`
) as "regexp_count"
FROM 
item_regexp ;
+-------------------------------------+--------------+
| regexp                              | regexp_count |
+-------------------------------------+--------------+
| ((pizza)\\|)((large|medium)\\|)     |            0 |
| ((pizza)\\|)((.*)\\|)((alldressed)) |            0 |
| ((beverage)\\|)((2_liter)\\|)       |            0 |
| ((pizza)\\|)((.*)\\|)((pepp))       |            0 |
+-------------------------------------+--------------+
4 rows in set
```

Is there something I've missed it the process so that QUERY #2 yield the same count value as QUERY #1 ?

Thanks for your help.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because when you define a literal

```
((beverage)\\|)((2_liter)\\|)
```

REGEXP sees the double \ as a single .
When you put it in a column, they are double \s, so it is equivalent to the literal

```
((beverage)\\\\|)((2_liter)\\\\|)
```

Which makes them different.  You had it right with the literals, but your insert into `item_regexp` is wrong.  Try the below instead

```
delete from `item_regexp`;
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('1', '((pizza)\\|)((large|medium)\\|)');
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('2', '((pizza)\\|)((.*)\\|)((alldressed))');
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('3', '((beverage)\\|)((2_liter)\\|)');
INSERT INTO `item_regexp` VALUES ('4', '((pizza)\\|)((.*)\\|)((pepp))');
```

Comment: Awesome ! I totally missed the escaping power of "\\"  it work like magic now. I will have to rethink how my sequences are stores and used by PHP and MySQL. 

Thanks for you help